# how to return latitude and longitude of the user in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geocoding

I want to make return latitude and longitude of the current user from the function and I have written the following code but this piece of code is saying "undefined" as a result. If anybody knows the solution, please answer

```
<script>
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var lat_lng = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        console.log(lat_lng);
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    var user_position = {};
    user_position.lat = position.coords.latitude; 
    user_position.lng = position.coords.longitude; 
    return user_position;
}
getLocation()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCurrentPosition` is executing **asynchronous** and `console.log(lat_lng);` is executed before you get the result from follow function:

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);`

You have to use a `callback` function instead.

```js
function getLocation(callback) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var lat_lng = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        console.log(position);
          var user_position = {};
          user_position.lat = position.coords.latitude; 
          user_position.lng = position.coords.longitude; 
          callback(user_position);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
getLocation(function(lat_lng){
  console.log(lat_lng);
});
```

[Working solution.](https://jsfiddle.net/nkjqvx9x/)

Comment: thank you, I'll try

Comment: @AbhayjeetSingh, i updated it with a working solution.